# cannot find 'ld' error building OpenCV4Android samples

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, cross-compiling

When trying to build libdetection_based_tracker in the OpenCV for Android Samples (2.4.3) with ndk-build ,I get the following error , similar error occurs to tutorial 3 and tutorial 4.

```
SharedLibrary  : libdetection_based_tracker.so 
collect2: cannot find 'ld'
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libdetection_based_tracker.so] Error 1
```

I don't know which ld this error refers to, I' m running an archlinux x64 installation.

Comment: ld is not a kind of error, it's the linker

Comment: I know it's the linker, I don't understand why it cannot find it. I don't know if it's the ld under /usr/bin or some ld under NDK folders.

Comment: Which NDK version have you installed?

Comment: verbose can be of some help in this case. if it is a Makefile try  **make VERBOSE=1** if it is a CMakeList.txt configure verbose makefile to **on**